# Unmarshalling JSON to Groovy in Grails Date

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, grails

I am working Grails 2.4 and Ajax. On the client I build JSON data as follows:

```
var data = {
    // ... not important
    date: new Date(
            parseInt($("#date_year").val()),
            parseInt($("#date_month").val()) - 1,
            parseInt($("#date_day").val())),
    // ...
};
```

I send the date with jQuery Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '${createLink(controller: 'report', action: 'save')}',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (respondData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert('Saved succesfully');
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('NOT SAVED!!!');
    }
});
```

In the report controller `ReportController` I have action `save(ThreatReport report)`. By some magic, Grails is able to unmarshall the JSON data to Groovy model represented by `ThreatReport report` argument (if anyone would point me to some documentation about how is this configured I would be much obliged).
`ThreatReport` class has a `Date` attribute (and other, but they are working fine). However, Grails seem to have troubles converting this date. In JavaScript I got

```
Wed Jun 10 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)
```

however, in the Groovy controller it is suddenly a day back:

```
Tue Jun 09 00:00:00 CEST 2015
```

As I stated, the rest of attributes are converted correctly.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using JavaScripts `toString()` to serialize a date. I'd use something like `momentjs` to format the date string and deserialize it using the same format pattern.

Comment: are you reffering to `JSON.stringify(data)`?

Comment: Not really - in your data I'd do `var data {... 'date': date.getTime()}` and convert that back to time (`new Date(jsonDateValue)`)

Comment: I dont think I understand you. I have three numbers, a year, a month and a day. From these numbers I create a date as is shown above. So you mean that I should create the date as I do it, then use `date.getTime()` and reconvert it back using `new Date(jsonDateValue)`? How could that help with it? when I use a helping print the date in `date` is correct. jQuery sends a correct date. Only the Groovy object holds a date with a day earlier.

Comment: For the time being I used a workaround -- I intentionally increment a day before sending it to the server (e.g., when I want 10/June I send 11/June), but this seems really clumsy and ugly. Not to mention that I have no idea whether it will work in all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so finally I got a solution. It is connected to timezones. However, the problem seems to be in a combination of a browser + my configuration of Grails. Browser serializes the date to a string in the zulu timezone, that means that after creating a date in my timezone (+02:00) e.g., 13. May 1999 00:00:00 it will get serialized to 12. May 1999 22:00:00.  However, the Grails was set to parse only the date and not the time, so in the end I got 12. May 1999 00:00:00 on the serverside. Then it seemed like a 24 hours shift. Now I use my own simple code to serialize it directly to the proper ISO date:

```
var data = {
    // ... not important
    date: $("#date_year").val() + "-" + $("#date_month").val() + "-" + $("#date_day").val(),
    // ...
};
```

So it will become a string "1999-5-13".

Answer (score 1):

I've had timezone issues in Java before, have you allready tried **-Duser.timezone** as an argument for your JVM startup?

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Example:

```
...java -Duser.timezone=Europe/London
```

Or (not sure if this works)

```
...java -Duser.timezone=Etc/GMT+2
```

**Update**

The java test code

```
Date date = new Date("2015/6/10");
System.out.println(date);
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(date.getTime(), DateTimeZone.UTC);
System.out.println(date2);
```

produces the output

```
Wed Jun 10 00:00:00 CEST 2015
2015-06-09T22:00:00.000Z
```

as an example for day switching problems because of timezone and/or DST Problems (in my case the testing JVM works with my correct timezone GMT+2, so I forced UTC in the second date with the timestamp from the first date).

Maybe this is not your specific problem, but maybe it helps when you pass the correct timezone as a parameter to the JVM of your **web application server** (for example in a tomcat startup script, **not** in your IDE). Try for example "Etc/GMT+2", when you're in Europe with daylight saving.

This must not but could be the root of your problem, I'm not familar with the frameworks you use but I know timezone and daylight saving problems can be complex/confusing, because it can be a mashup of custom and default settings (OS, JVM) and how frameworks deal with dates with/without times and/or timezones.

In case it helps don't forget to adjust JVM calls on other systems for your application regarding the timezone parameter :-)

Comment: I've tried adding it to Configuration in IntelliJ Idea, but it does not seem to make any change. Anyway, it changes only the day, so I am not really sure how could timezones affect it..

Comment: after a further inspection I can say that both server and client works with the same timezone.. it seems that the problem is in unmarshalling.. anyway, does not shift the time for few hours, as I would expect in case of a different timezone, however always a single one day, a whole day back.. If I will find out something more I will let you know.. thanks for the   effort anyway :)